# limitations Google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a locator based on Google maps. It seems like there is a maximum on the requests because after a period of time the search function is nog working anymore. When I look at the API information I only have 150 request at this time and the max is 2500. Who can help me with this?

http://google.stoepje.biz/ 
http://locator.stoepje.biz/

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that there is a limitation on Google Maps API requests within a given timeframe. This is detailed in the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits).

The solution is to purchase a Google Maps API for Business license, which [increases the number of API requests you can make per day](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits).